# OpenCv camera window not opening only webcam light is glowing

Tags: python, opencv

Hello am working on facial emotion recognition for which I am using webcam for live video input ,to achieve this am using opencv , when i run the code the webcam light glows but am not able to get the webcam window, though there are no errors thrown but still not able to get the camera window only webcam light glows.

Here is my code below :

```
import cv2
path='haarcascade_frontalface_Default.xml'
font_scale=1.5
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

rectangle_bgr=(255,255,255)
img=np.zeros((500,500))

text="Text is written for box"
(text_width,text_height)=cv2.getTextSize(text,font,fontScale=font_scale,thickness=1)[0]
text_offset_x=10
text_offset_y=img.shape[0] - 25

box_coords=((text_offset_x,text_offset_y),(text_offset_x + text_width +2,text_offset_y - text_height -2))
cv2.rectangle(img,box_coords[0], box_coords[1], rectangle_bgr,cv2.FILLED)
cv2.putText(img,text,(text_offset_x,text_offset_y),font,fontScale=font_scale,color=(0,0,0),thickness=1)

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(1)
if not cap.isOpened():
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
        raise IOError("Cannot Open WebCam")

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    faceCascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+ 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)
    for x,y,w,h in facess:
        roi_gray=gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_color=frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)#bgr
        facess=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        if len(facess)==0:
            print("face not detected")
        else:
            for(ex,ey,ew,eh)in facess:
                face_roi=roi_color[ey: ey+eh, ex:ex+ew]
    
    final_image=cv2.resize(face_roi,(224,224))
    final_image=np.expand_dims(final_image,axis=0)
    final_image=final_image/255.0

    font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    Predictions=new_model.predict(final_image)

    font_scale=1.5
    font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

if(np.argmax(Predictions)==0):
        status="Angry"
        x1,y1,w1,h1=0,0,175,75
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,x1),(x1 + w1,y1 + h1),(0,0,0),-1)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(x1 +int(w1/10),y1 + int(h1/2)),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(100,150),font,3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(0,0,255))
        
elif (np.argmax(Predictions)==1):
        status="Disgust"
        x1,y1,w1,h1=0,0,175,75
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,x1),(x1 + w1,y1 + h1),(0,0,0),-1)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(x1 +int(w1/10),y1 + int(h1/2)),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(100,150),font,3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(0,0,255))
        
elif (np.argmax(Predictions)==2):
        status="Fear"
        x1,y1,w1,h1=0,0,175,75
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,x1),(x1 + w1,y1 + h1),(0,0,0),-1)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(x1 +int(w1/10),y1 + int(h1/2)),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(100,150),font,3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(0,0,255))
        
elif (np.argmax(Predictions)==3):
        status="Happy"
        x1,y1,w1,h1=0,0,175,75
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,x1),(x1 + w1,y1 + h1),(0,0,0),-1)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(x1 +int(w1/10),y1 + int(h1/2)),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(100,150),font,3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(0,0,255))
        
elif (np.argmax(Predictions)==4):
        status="Sad"
        x1,y1,w1,h1=0,0,175,75
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,x1),(x1 + w1,y1 + h1),(0,0,0),-1)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(x1 +int(w1/10),y1 + int(h1/2)),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(100,150),font,3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(0,0,255))
        
        
elif (np.argmax(Predictions)==5):
        status="Surprise"
        x1,y1,w1,h1=0,0,175,75
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,x1),(x1 + w1,y1 + h1),(0,0,0),-1)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(x1 +int(w1/10),y1 + int(h1/2)),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(100,150),font,3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255))
else:
        status="Neutral"
        x1,y1,w1,h1=0,0,175,75
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,x1),(x1 + w1,y1 + h1),(0,0,0),-1)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(x1 +int(w1/10),y1 + int(h1/2)),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(frame,status,(100,150),font,3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(0,0,255))
        
        
        cv2.imshow("face emotion Recognition", frame)
        if cv2.waitkey(2)& 0xFF ==ord('q'):
             break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

can anyone tell me whats the error, is it my system  error as its bit slow or there are some error in code? Only the webcam light is glowing but no camera window. I checked my webcam is working fine properly  when i open camera application .

Answer (score 0):

change

`cv2.waitkey(2)` to `cv2.waitKey(0)`

`K` in waitKey should be capital

Comment: I have changed that but still it's not working

Comment: Which development environment you are using.

Comment: Am using jupyter notebook

Comment: Share the required files (XML etc), I will run it on my own laptop.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your cv2.imshow('')...if by any chance it get commented..this error occurs... otherwise give it try by  using that segment of code outside your else statement...maybe that can solve the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).